# http 404 error in eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse, tomcat

got this error when i created a single html page and i have also have another web project in eclipse
HTTP Status 404 - /Angular/

---

type Status report

message /Angular/

description The requested resource is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.82
HTTP Status 404 - /Angular/

---

type Status report

message /Angular/

description The requested resource is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.82

Answer (score 0):

When deploying a server in eclipse, ensure that you've added your eclipse project as a `web module` to the server. To see that on your existing server, double click it, and go to the `modules` tab.

Now, take note of the `path` at which you've deployed the module. You may need to change that path to `/Angular` instead of your eclipse project name.